# Why Mathematica doesn't simplify this multiplication?$c^{-L} (c r){^L}$

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why Mathematica doesn't simplify this multiplication? I don't know Mathematica it can or not? Please accept my ignorance :)

[image]

c^-L (c r)^L

Comment: Check out [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it isn't always true that the simplification can be made. Consider the following substitutions:

```
subs = {L -> 1/2, c -> -1, r -> 1};
```

Then,

```
c^-L (c*r)^-L /. subs
```

yields

> -1

but

```
r^-L /. subs
```

yields

```
1
```

Answer (score 3):

It is true if c is positive:

```
FullSimplify[c^-L (c*r)^L, Assumptions -> {c > 0}]
r^L
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can force

```
c^-L (c r)^L/.(a_ b_)^c_:>a^c b^c
```

which is equal to [`PowerExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html)

As others said, this rule is true when c>0